# Nodejs Http Request returning a split buffer - unable to display image in the Frontend

Tags: node.js, image, http, request

Im rewriting code from 'request' to 'http' because support ends. I am very sure that my problem lies in the encoding. in the http.request i get d as Buffer but multiple instances. If i extract the first one it loads just a portion of the image but i cannot combine them. If i combine data like i did here the Content type is lost and i cant display it. i also tried setting content-type in the header but what if i dont get a png back.

```
    if(req.Encoding === 'binary'){
       Header = {
         "Accept-Encoding": "deflate",
         "encoding": "null",
       }
     }
     const options = {
       hostname: GlobalConfigModel.AS400Host,
       port: Number(GlobalConfigModel.AS400Port),
       path: Path,
       method: req.Method,
       headers: Header,
     }

     let mdl = new RestResponseModel()

     // GET METHOD
     if(req.Method === 'GET'){
       http.request(options, res => {
         var data: any = []
         res.on('data', d => {
             data += d
             mdl.Data = Buffer.from(data);
         })
         res.on('end', () => {
           resume(mdl)
         })
       }).end()
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was not fully understanding the http request syntax the on 'data' part of the request should only read data and push it into a variable. after that the logic that parses the data to the wanted format should be done in the on 'end' portion of the statement

```
      if(req.Method === 'GET'){
        http.request(options, res => {
          var chunkBuffer: any = []
          var type: any
          res.on('data', chunk => {
            chunkBuffer.push(chunk)
          })
          res.on('end', () => {
            let dataBuffer = Buffer.concat(chunkBuffer)
            if( req.Encoding === 'utf8'){
              var stringBuffer = dataBuffer.toString('utf8')
              mdl.Data = JSON.parse(stringBuffer)
            } else{
              mdl.Data = dataBuffer
            }
            resume(mdl)
          })
        }).end()
      }
```